# Sorting arrays of objects in this manner, of frequency

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this type of array of object

```
students = [
    {
        "name": "Ana Barbique",
        "category":"B"
    }
    {
        "name": "Marko Polo",
        "category":"B"
    }
    {
        "name": "Nick Harper",
        "category":"A"
    }
]
```

What I want it to have a array of object of this type:

```
sum = [
    {
        "category": "A",
        "count" : 1
    }
    {
        "category": "B",
        "count" : 2
    }
]
```

So essentially I want to have the array of object have the categories that appear in students and their count. The order doesn't matter. I have not done this before.

Comment: What have you tried to do to create the `sum` object? Add an example of something you've tried in your question.

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: Quentin - see this other question with a great answer for just this type of thing: [loop-through-multiple-array-and-keep-count-of-each-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44122604/loop-through-multiple-array-and-keep-count-of-each-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pure loop & lookup approach. Yuri Tarabanko answer is neater.

They key to this approach is to use the check array object to hold the index of each category in the sum[] array.  It is a useful technique to know.

```js
var students = [
    {
        "name": "Ana Barbique",
        "category":"B"
    },
    {
        "name": "Marko Polo",
        "category":"B"
    },
    {
        "name": "Nick Harper",
        "category":"A"
    }
]

var sum = [], check = [], obj;
for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i = i + 1) {

  obj = students[i]; 
  if ( check[obj.category] !== undefined ) { 
    // object has already been seen so add to sum array count
    sum[check[obj.category]].count = sum[check[obj.category]].count + 1; 
    
  }
   else {
   // object has not been seen so insert new.
   sum.push({"category": obj.category, "count": 1});
   check[obj.category] = sum.length - 1; // note index of category in sum array.   
   }


}
console.log('sum = ' + JSON.stringify(sum));
```

Answer (score 1):

First create categories count object by reducing `students` array

```
const categories = students
   .reduce((cat, student) => (
       cat[student.category]++ || (cat[student.category] = 1), cat
   ), {})
```

Then iterate over categories' keys to create required array

```
const sum = Object
   .keys(categories)
   .map(name => ({category: name, count: categories[name]}))
```

Comment: Yury - I tried your answer and get 'message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list",' error. Could you edit your answer and add a working snippet?

Comment: Missed a closing parentheses while copying. Thanks.