# Loop through multiple array and keep count of each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

My `JSON` looks something like this:

```
[{
    "Name": "Test Post",
    "Id": 123,
    "ProductHandlingTypes": [{
         "Id": 1,
         "Name": "Type 1"
     },  
     {
         "Id": 2,
         "Name": "Type 2"
    }]
}, 
{
    "Name": "Test Post 2",
    "Id": 124,
    "ProductHandlingTypes": [{
        "Id": 3,
        "Name": "Type 3"
    },     
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Type 1"
    }]
}]
```

So, in essence, I would like to be able to loop through all of the post's product handling types and compare them to a list of product handling types and anytime there is a match, I would like to keep track of how many times that specific type has been matched/used/found.

I am currently checking for matches this way, but I'm unsure of how to keep a tally of each product type:

```
postDataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: { 
            url: "/path/to/get/posts",
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        parse: function (response) {
            // Get all product handling types
            viewModel.productHandlingTypesDataSource.fetch(function() {
                var types = this.data();
                // Loop through all of the posts
                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    // Loop through each product handling type for each post
                    for (var j = 0; j < response[i].ProductHandlingTypes.length; j++) {
                        // Loop through every product handling type
                        for (var k = 0; k < types.length; k++) {
                            // Check if product handling type matches the post's product handling type(s)
                            if (response[i].ProductHandlingTypes[j].Name == types[k].Name) {
                                // Keep track of how many times this name matches
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })

            return response;
        }
    }
})
```

I've had some trouble trying to put this issue into words so if I need to clarify some more just let me know.

Comment: How would you like the output to look? Do you want something such as an object with the product type ids as the keys, and the counts as the values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting Occurrences of Object Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957390/counting-occurrences-of-object-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce` like this:

```js
var a = [{"Name":"TestPost","Id":123,"ProductHandlingTypes":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Type1"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Type2"}]},{"Name":"TestPost2","Id":124,"ProductHandlingTypes":[{"Id":3,"Name":"Type3"},{"Id":1,"Name":"Type1"}]}];

var b = a.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  cur.ProductHandlingTypes.map(({Name}) => Name).forEach(n => acc[n] = (acc[n] || 0) + 1);
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(b)
```

It loops through your array and increments `Type n` values or creates them is they don't exist.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!