# Convert reduce function to work with IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ecmascript-6, reduce

Alright, so I had some help a couple months ago with coming up with a solution to keep count of the elements in an array: [Loop through multiple array and keep count of each element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44122604/loop-through-multiple-array-and-keep-count-of-each-element)

This solution worked perfectly for me until I realized that it's using `ES6` which is not supported by `IE 11`. I've tried to convert it to using functions instead of the arrow function so that it'll work across all browsers but am having some issues.

Here is the current code that does not work in IE:

```
var b = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    cur.ProductHandlingTypes.map(({ Name }) => Name).forEach(n => acc[n] = (acc[n] || 0) + 1);
    return acc;
},
{});
```

If someone could guide me on what needs to be changed here so that it works in IE that would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE 11 doesn't support arrow functions [1], nor destructuring [2], so convert it to ES5 syntax:

```
var b = data.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  cur.ProductHandlingTypes
    .map(function(obj) {
      return obj.Name
    })
    .forEach(function(n) {
      return acc[n] = (acc[n] || 0) + 1
    })

  return acc
}, {});
```

[1] http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

[2] http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-destructuring

Comment: Thank you! I knew that arrow functions weren't supported but didn't realize that destructuring wasn't as well.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the de-structuring.

```
cur.ProductHandlingTypes.map((obj) => obj.Name).forEach(...
```